# Parsing a sentence with の and に missing(?)

Tags: particles, parsing

[image]

I saw this tweet earlier today. I find it difficult to understand the underlined portion. This is the first time I saw 目指すよう without に or な following it. The same goes with 近く. It looks like an adverb, but I'm sure it's not modifying 要請する. Is it 近くの with の omitted? This is not a newspaper headline, but what's with the omission of に and の?

Comment: Thanks for cropping the image naruto. (Apparently, the image is much larger than my cellphone screen) Did you have to download and reupload it just to crop it?

Comment: Yes, I just made another (partial) screenshot from your image and uploaded it.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23585/what-are-the-differences-between-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab-and-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-when-used-to-link-sentences

Comment: @Leebo thanks. So whether there's 「、」 or not, it's similar to ように only slightly more formal, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace ように with よう in some situations:

- When it describe a purpose ("so that ～")

  > 字幕なしで映画が見えるように勉強します。
  > 字幕なしで映画が見えるよう勉強します。
  > I will study so that I can watch movies without subtitles.
- When it expresses a wish ("I wish ～", "May ～")

  > 神のご加護がありますように。
  > 神のご加護がありますよう。
  > May the God bless you.
- When it describes the content of 頼む, 命令する, 要求する, 言う, etc.

  > 来るように言って。
  > 来るよう言って。
  > Tell him to come.

There is almost no difference, but I feel よう is slightly more literary. (I'm not sure if "formal" is the correct word here. ように is safe in the most formal settings.)

You cannot drop に when it means "similarly to ～", "as ～" or "like ～".

- 鳥のように飛んだ。 It flew like a bird.
- 彼のように美しい人はいない。 No one is as beautiful as him.
- ご存じのようにこちらは冬です。 As you know, it's winter here.

---

This 近く is an adverb on its own (my dictionary says so). 近くの経済界 would mean "nearby world of economics", which makes little sense. 多く also has a special adverbial usage ("often", "mainly").

Comment: Thanks! I just checked what 近く means and I didn't know that it can mean "soon", similar to but not replaceable by すぐに